# route in web.php did not read the url sent using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm new in Laravel 5.4. Here is my question:
I add menu for admin in app/Http/Middleware/AdminMenu.php as below:

```
if ($user->can('read-calpblat-criterias')) {
            $menu->add([ 
                'url' => action('Calpblat\Ploscriteria@index'), 
                'title' => 'Criteria for PLO',
                'icon' => 'fa fa-cubes',
                'order' => 7
            ]);
        }
```

Then in route/web.php i added this route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'calpblat'], function () {
                Route::resource('subjects', 'Calpblat\Subjects');
                Route::resource('pblcases', 'Calpblat\Pblcases');
                Route::resource('rubics', 'Calpblat\Rubics');
                Route::resource('criteriagroups', 'Calpblat\Criteriagroups');
                Route::resource('criterias', 'Calpblat\Criterias');
                Route::resource('typeassessments', 'Calpblat\Typeassessments');
                Route::resource('plos', 'Calpblat\Plos');
                **Route::resource('ploscriteria', 'Calpblat\Ploscriteria');**
            });
```

But when i click the new menu, it's redirect to default controller :

```
 Route::get('/', 'Dashboard\Dashboard@index');
```

Why is that happen? It's did not redirect to route ploscriteria that i added.
Is there some place that i have to add the new route?
Its a great pleasure if someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: Check in the page source that you have proper URL add with the menu ?

Comment: @DsRaj this is the url for my menu :  
$menu->add([
                    'url' => 'calpblat/ploscriteria',
                    'title' => 'Criteria for PLO',
                    'icon' => 'fa fa-cubes',
                    'order' => 7,
                ]);

Comment: I mean when checking the source(HTML code in browser) then check what is the URL there?

Comment: provide us the restriction rule .. in the `can()` method

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for misunderstanding. This is the page source for the URL. `<li><a href="http://localhost/calpblat/calpblat/ploscriteria" ><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> <span>Criteria for PLO</span></a></li>`.

Comment: I think it's not the proper URL, Just add the below url hardcoded and check it for a while
http://localhost/calpblat//ploscriteria

Comment: @Demonyowh in the $user->can() method, its only check if the login user has the permission to access the menu.

Comment: i know right .. that's why i want to see .. maybe that should help us help you ..

Comment: @DsRaj i try to change but page not found. For information, the controller for new menu that i added is inside the folder name 'controllers/calpblat'. My sistem also name  'calpblat'.

Comment: @Demonyowh I'm sorry but where can i find the restriction rule that u asked? As i search from the can() method, it just check the data in database whether the user login has the permission or not.

Comment: Just add something like  this in the place of URL action('Controller@actionName')
in your case action('calpblat/ControllerName@actionName')

Comment: @DsRaj i added as below: <br/>

`Route::resource('ploscriteria', 'Calpblat\Ploscriteria@index');` in web.php file but show error : Method [index@index] does not exist.

This is my controller looks like : <br/>

`class Ploscriteria extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}`

Comment: @KuntumMawar 
Route::resource('ploscriteria', 'Calpblat\Ploscriteria'); It is fine in the Web.php no need to change over there you just need to change the URL

$menu->add([
                    'url' => action('Calpblat\Ploscriteria@index'),
                    'title' => 'Criteria for PLO',
                    'icon' => 'fa fa-cubes',
                    'order' => 7,
                ]);

Comment: @DsRaj I'm trying to add as u told but error as below. Its seems like it's read the route first.  <br/>

Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
(1/1) NotFoundHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 179)

Comment: Add the updated content in the question

Comment: @DsRaj ok done updated.

Comment: @KuntumMawar Are you sure you update the question because I didn't find anything updated

Comment: @DsRaj Sorry but it's updated in my view. i update the content as below :

<br/>
`$menu->add([
                **'url' => 'calpblat/ploscriteria@index',**
                'title' => 'Criteria for PLO',
                'icon' => 'fa fa-cubes',
                'order' => 7,
            ]);`

Comment: You need to add this in question not in comment 
any way add these line 
$menu->add([ **'url' => action('Calpblat\Ploscriteria@actionName'),** 'title' => 'Criteria for PLO', 'icon' => 'fa fa-cubes', 'order' => 7]);

Comment: @DsRaj Ok i added these line $menu->add([ 'url' => action('Calpblat\Ploscriteria@index'), 'title' => 'Criteria for PLO', 'icon' => 'fa fa-cubes', 'order' => 7]); . But the page still redirect to default page after login. .:

Comment: Try to add hard coded URL and then check?

Answer (score 0):

try it

please change it

```
'url' => action(route('ploscriteria.index')),
```

Comment: Hi @Sohil Shingala..i change code as shown but error like this  ` (1/1) InvalidArgumentException

Action App\Http\Controllers\http://localhost/calpblat/calpblat/ploscriteria not defined.`